# Считать с MySQL определенный столбец

Tags: java, mysql, select

Java проект подключается к удаленной БД MySQL, которая хранит 4 столба и 3 строки.
Каким образом с помощью Java можно считать определенный столбец, а не все строки что там есть? Привожу пример кода:

```
public static String select(String result) {
        String query = "SELECT tags, status FROM test.task";

        try {

            // Подключеник к MySQL серверу
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // getting Statement object to execute query
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            // Выполнение запроса SELECT (query)
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            rs.findColumn("status");
                rs.next();
                int status = rs.getInt("status"); // Считывание значения Integer из колонки "status"
                String tag = rs.getString("tags");

                switch (status) {
                    case 2:
                        tag = rs.getString("tags"); // Считывание значения String из колонки "tags"
                        result = tag;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tag = rs.getString("tags"); // Считывание значения String из колонки "tags"
                        result = tag;
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        tag = rs.getString("tags"); // Считывание значения String из колонки "tags"
                        result = tag;
                        break;

            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            //close connection ,stmt and resultset here

            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
            try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

4 Столбца: id, title, tags, status. В "status" столбце 3 значения: "0", "1", "2".
Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа увидев столбец "status", считывала его значение. К примеру, если нашел значение "2" - то выводит определенную ячейку столбца "tags", которая на той же строке, что и "2" в колонке "status". Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Так ваш текущий код уже всё делает что вам нужно

Comment: @ArchDemon , хорошо, как тогда сделать правильную обработку?
просто на выходе он получается считывает вообще всю строку, а мне нужно их правильно обработать

Comment: А я не пойму чего вы пытаетесь добиться. Так что не понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под "правильная обработка" и чем вам мешает "вся строка".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаешь resultSet, затем запускаешь цикл while(resultSet.next())
Он построчно считывает данные из таблицы и в этот момент ты сможешь вытащить определенный столбец (нумерация начинается с 1) с помощью методов getInt, getString ... вытаскиваешь от туда данные вот пример:

```
ArryList<int> i = new ArryList;
ArryList<String> s = new ArryList;
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query);
            while(res.next()){
                i.add(resset.getInt(1));
                s.add(resset.getString(2));
            }
```